# build fail with cxf-codegen-plugin

Tags: eclipse, maven, dependencies

I imported an existing project with modules into eclipse and this is existing code created by a third party that I need to try and understand. But one project keeps failed on mvn clean install and the following error keeps occurring; which seems to be related to a webservice issue:

```
 ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-
 plugin:2.7.6:wsdl2java (xxxxxxxxxx) on project 
 xxxxxxxxxx: 
 com/sun/tools/xjc/BadCommandLineException: 
  com.sun.tools.xjc.BadCommandLineException -> [Help 1]
```

This is user security project that verifies credentials using a webservice.

Answer (score 1):

If you activate "DEBUG"-mode for Maven and "Print exception stack traces", and the error is a NoClassDefFoundError for the BadCommandLineException, then I solved it by providing a dependency to the cxf-codegen-plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            ...
        </execution>
    </executions>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0-b180725.0644</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```